# Angular-CLI: 'ng serve' inlines the Bootstrap multiple times

Tags: angular, angular-cli, bootstrap-4

I'm using Angular CLI with Bootstrap 4. After some painful setup I was ready to go. Once the 'ng serve' finishes the build into memory and I open the app, after inspecting some elements I've noticed that the bootstrap classes are present multiple times.

After inspecting the `<head>` I can see there are `<style>` elements (3x) and all of them contain the bootstrap classes.

My app setup is as follows:

```
- SRC
   |- APP
   |   |- TOOLBAR
   |   |      |- toolbar.component.scss
   |   |- app.component.scss
   |- app.scss
   |- variables.scss
```

in variables.scss

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
...
```

in app.scss, app.component.scss, toolbar.component.scss

```
@import "./variables"
```

Each time I add another component with its own scss class that imports the 'variables', another `<style>` content is added with complete Bootstrap.css inside.

in my .angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
        "app.scss"
      ],
```

and finally, in my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
"bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^1.6.6",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

},

Any ideas why is it multiplied all the time??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` is only variables and mixins, otherwise every time that you're importing it inside a component that has encapsulated CSS it will create another style for you.

Try to import all the CSS stuff in the root app and inside your component only import the variables.

Comment: thanks, I've kept the structure as is but in the variables.scss I've used '@import ../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables' and '@import ../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins', and added the 'bootstrap.min.css' to angular-cli.json 'styles'. Thanks